# Javascript animation glitch

Tags: css

I have written a simple function .onload where a 'p' and 'h1' tag go from opacity:0; to opacity 1;.
The animation is fine and everything but sometimes while the animation is happening, it looks like the p and h1 tags have a background-color set to gray while the animation  is happening and then it disappears once the animation ends and this only occurs on firefox.
[see animation bug here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhKIO.png)

```
const abouth1 = document.querySelector(".about-h1");
const aboutp = document.querySelector(".about-p");
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo");

function fadeFunction() {
  abouth1.classList.add("about-show-h1");
  aboutp.classList.add("about-show-p");
  logo.classList.add("logo-show");
}

window.onload = fadeFunction();
```

```
.about-h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1.5s;
  transform: translateX(45%);
}

.about-p {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: translateX(-65%);
}
.about-show-p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.about-show-h1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```
 <h1 class="about-h1">
            My name is Drinos Shala, <br />
            and I am a senior software developer who <br />
            specializes in front-end technologies.
          </h1>
          <p class="about-p">
            My job is to ensure your website is pixel perfect in every
            dimension,
            <br />
            years of working in this field have granted me the experience needed
            <br />
            to deploy every website I start in great success! <br />Let's get in
            touch so we can get started on your dream website for your dream
            business.
          </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any third party firefox extensions try to remove them, looks fine on my Firefox browser and adding a night-mode extension (even though turned off) caused this bug.